# How to use spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate with Google Cloud Functions and NodeJS and 'googleapis' module

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` function in the same way as described [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20504-update-google-sheet-cell-values). This example uses Google Apps Script. I would like to do it using Google Cloud Functions instead.

The [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) API documentation is available. Note that it is different from the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) , which has a different syntax. I'm interested in using the former.

I would like to do the same using the environment: Google Cloud Functions + **nodejs8** + `googleapis` module.

This is the example code for Google Apps Script from the link above:

```
function updateGoogleSheet(spreadsheetId) {

  /* Written by Amit Agarwal */
  /* Web: ctrlq.org  Email: amit@labnol.org */
  
  var data = [
    { 
      range: "Sheet1!A1",   // Update single cell
      values: [
        ["A1"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!B1:B3", // Update a column
      values: [
        ["B1"],["B2"],["B3"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!C1:E1", // Update a row
      values: [
        ["C1","D1","E1"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!F1:H2", // Update a 2d range
      values: [
        ["F1", "F2"],
        ["H1", "H2"]
      ]
    }];
  
  var resource = {
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    data: data
  };
  
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
  
}
```

.

This is the above code in the new environment:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4'});
const auth = new google.auth.JWT (credentials.client_email, null, credentials.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);

function updateGoogleSheet (spreadsheetId) {

  /* Written by Amit Agarwal */
  /* Web: ctrlq.org  Email: amit@labnol.org */

  var data = [
    { 
      range: "Sheet1!A1",   // Update single cell
      values: [
    ["A1"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!B1:B3", // Update a column
      values: [
    ["B1"],["B2"],["B3"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!C1:E1", // Update a row
      values: [
    ["C1","D1","E1"]
      ]
    },
    {
      range: "Sheet1!F1:H2", // Update a 2d range
      values: [
    ["F1", "F2"],
    ["H1", "H2"]
      ]
    }];

  var resource = {
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    auth: auth,
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    data: data
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate (resource);

}
```

However this gives the following error:

`Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data[range]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'data[range]' could not be found in request message. Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data[values]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'data[values]' could not be found in request message. at Gaxios.request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7) response: { config: [Object], data: [Object], headers: [Object], status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request' }, config: { url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/......spreadsheetId....../values:batchUpdate?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&data%5Brange%5D=Sheet1%21A1&data%5Bvalues%5D=A1&data%5Brange%5D=Sheet1%21B1%3AB3&data%5Bvalues%5D=B1&data%5Bvalues%5D=B2&data%5Bvalues%5D=B3&data%5Brange%5D=Sheet1%21C1%3AE1&data%5Bvalues%5D=C1&data%5Bvalues%5D=D1&data%5Bvalues%5D=E1&data%5Brange%5D=Sheet1%21F1%3AH2&data%5Bvalues%5D=F1&data%5Bvalues%5D=F2&data%5Bvalues%5D=H1&data%5Bvalues%5D=H2', method: 'POST', paramsSerializer: [Function], headers: [Object], params: [Object], validateStatus: [Function], retry: true, responseType: 'json', retryConfig: [Object] }, code: 400, errors: [ [Object] ]`

My question is, how to format the **resource** parameter to **spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate ()** to make the request succeed?

I couldn't find any documentation on this, but it seems possible from the original code example above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also I added the versions that the script was tested. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for posting lots of other related answers. I found many of them useful while working on this earlier.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The basic request body for each API is the same for various language. But the method for setting the request body is different for each language. When you want to know how to set the request body for the language you want to use, I think that to see the sample script of Quickstart for each language is useful. And also I check the GitHub of each library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put the values using the method of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate of Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to put and get values for the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var resource = {
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  auth: auth,
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  data: data
};
```

#### To:

```
var resource = {
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  auth: auth,
  resource: { data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }
};
```

#### Note:

- If an error occurs, please confirm the following points.

  - The Spreadsheet is shared with the Service account.
  - Sheets API is enabled.
- I could confirm that the script of above modification worked with googleapis of v42.0.0(latest) at Node.js v8.0.0 and v12.9.0(latest).

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, I've been able to read and write values to the spreadsheet, using this module, `googleapis`.  (As apparently `@google-cloud/sheets` is not currently available for nodejs8 runtime or not available at all). Let me check the version you suggested, but I think I have already tried that variant. (I've tried a few)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As per the comments, neither the `params` or `requestBody` properties appear viable (even though both are documented on the home page of the [github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)).
From the samples I've seen, the `requestBody` parameter is always paired with a service that is initialized with oauth credentials as follows:

```
const sheets = google.sheets({"version":"v4", "auth":auth});
```

Where the request no longer has the auth property:

```
var resource = {
    "spreadsheetId": spreadsheetId,
    "requestBody": {
        "validInputOption":"USER_ENTERED",
        "data":data
    }
}

sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate (resource);
```

The above should work. If not, users will at least be aware of the issue.

---

̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶[̶g̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶p̶i̶ ̶n̶o̶d̶e̶j̶s̶ ̶c̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶]̶[̶1̶]̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶t̶l̶y̶.̶ ̶[̶A̶c̶c̶o̶r̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶]̶[̶2̶]̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶y̶ ̶a̶ ̶`̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶B̶o̶d̶y̶`̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶e̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶s̶:̶

```
̶̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶s̶p̶r̶e̶a̶d̶S̶h̶e̶e̶t̶I̶d̶:̶ ̶s̶p̶r̶e̶a̶d̶S̶h̶e̶e̶t̶I̶d̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶:̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶B̶o̶d̶y̶:̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶I̶n̶p̶u̶t̶O̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶:̶"̶U̶S̶E̶R̶_̶E̶N̶T̶E̶R̶E̶D̶"̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶d̶a̶t̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶;̶
```

̶I̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶t̶i̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶U̶R̶L̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶e̶t̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶P̶O̶S̶T̶ ̶b̶o̶d̶i̶e̶s̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶l̶i̶c̶i̶t̶,̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶s̶:̶

```
̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶:̶a̶u̶t̶h̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶:̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶s̶p̶r̶e̶a̶d̶S̶h̶e̶e̶t̶I̶d̶:̶s̶p̶r̶e̶a̶d̶S̶h̶e̶e̶t̶I̶d̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶B̶o̶d̶y̶:̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶I̶n̶p̶u̶t̶O̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶:̶"̶U̶S̶E̶R̶_̶E̶N̶T̶E̶R̶E̶D̶"̶,̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶d̶a̶t̶a̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶;̶
```

---

**Addendum**

Tanaike's solution is also viable.

Comment: I have tried both solutions, but neither of them worked. The first one gives the error: `Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "valid_input_option": Cannot find field. at Gaxios.request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)`

Comment: The second one gives the error: `Error: Missing required parameters: spreadsheetId at createAPIRequestAsync (/srv/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:109:15) at Object.createAPIRequest (/srv/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:44:16) at Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.batchUpdate (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/sheets/v4.js:480:44) at ... at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)`  However Tanaike's solution worked. Thank you for taking the time to answer this, I hope it will help others.

Comment: The second version gives that error even if I change `spreadSheetId` to `spreadsheetId`, same result.

Comment: In my environment, when `resource` is replaced to `requestBody`, an error of `Invalid JSON payload received.` occurs as @gregn3 's comment. In this case, the latest version of googleapis was used. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52316460/7108653. They say that v30.0.0 works `resource` and `requestBody`. But in my environment, `requestBody` occurs the error at v30.0.0. So I cannot still find the reason and the method for using `requestBody`. I apologize for this.